tabular cube in Visual Studio not showing parameters
I have a tabular cube created in Visual Studio Professional 2022 (created with the 'Microsoft Analysis Services Projects' extension).  I created parameters for my data source (an Azure SQL MI instance).  When I'm in the expression editor (Power Query Editor), I can see my parameters as items in my query list.  But, when I access Query \ Manage Parameters, none appear.  And, after I deploy my cube to a Power BI workspace (under Premium capacity), when I try to configure deployment rules in a deployment pipeline, I only see an option for 'Data source rule'; 'Parameter rules' is disabled.
How can I resolve this?  That is, how can I make my parameters actually act as parameters, i.e., to appear in Manage Parameters in Visual Studio and to give me the 'Parameter rules' option in a deployment pipeline in the Power BI web service?
